# Models for fat tails

Tags: modeling, fat-tails

I am trying to model stock returns and I thought it would be interesting to make a comparison between some well-known models. 
Could anyone name some well-known models that are used in the presence of fat tails? I was wondering if someone could provide me with an overview of alternatives. I am especially interested in somewhat more sophisticated models.

Comment: An example: a simple regression model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is assumed to follow some heavy-tailed distribution. The model coefficients and perhaps the tail-heaviness parameter could be estimated by maximum likelihood. It could be estimated by OLS as well but OLS estimates would not coincide with ML estimates. But what are you trying to model? And why do you need a sophisticated model; do you want to make an impression or is the relation you are modelling very complex?

Comment: @RichardHardy Thank you. I am trying to model stock returns and I thought it would be interesting to make a comparison between some well-known models. Your suggestion is certainly a good one but I'm also interested in knowing whether there exist certain other techniques that I can compare such approaches with. Are there for instance more sophisticated models that are surprising and interesting to investigate?

Comment: A natural competitor of GARCH-type models is stochastic volatility (SV) model class; I think GARCH is a special case of SV models. I suspect the estimation of SV models is quite involved and the models look kind of fancy (but this is just an opinion).

Comment: @RichardHardy Stochastic volatility models seem interesting. Do you have a good reference where they use this in a time-series context? Because most references that I found are applied to option pricing. Btw: if you make your comments into an answer I will certainly upvote and might also accept it later on. Thanks again :)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Initial answer** 
An example of a model with heavy-tailed errors: a simple regression model $y=\beta_0+\beta_1 x+\varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ is assumed to follow some heavy-tailed distribution. The model coefficients and perhaps the tail-heaviness parameter could be estimated by maximum likelihood. It could be estimated by OLS as well but OLS estimates would not coincide with ML estimates.

**Answer specific to stock return modelling** 
A natural competitor of GARCH-type models is stochastic volatility (SV) model class; I think GARCH is a special case of SV models. I suspect the estimation of SV models is quite involved and the models look kind of fancy (but this is just an opinion).

Some literature on SV models:

- Asai et al. ["Multivariate stochastic volatility: A review"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07474930600713564#) (2006)
- Broto & Ruiz ["Estimation methods for stochastic volatility models: A survey"](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1467-6419.2004.00232.x/full) (2004)

I cannot give a good recommendation for any applied paper because I never worked on stochastic volatility myself. However, I am pretty sure that stochastic volatility models have not only been applied for option pricing but also for modelling returns on futures and stocks as well. Hopefully, you will find some relevant references in the two survey papers above.

Comment: May I ask you one more question? I realized that I don't yet fully understand the link between fat-tails and SV models. Could you provide any reference or intuition on why and whether they would capture this well? (Because it seems that most SV models still use normally distributed errors).

Comment: I don't know much about SV models, but I guess the argument could be similar to that for GARCH. A process with GARCH-type errors will be heavy-tailed even if the standardized errors (errors divided by their conditional standard deviations) are normally distributed. Also, you need not assume normally-distributed errors. In GARCH models, $t(3)$ or $t(4)$ errors (Student $t$-distribution with 3 or 4 degrees of freedom) are often found to be more plausible/likely than normal errors. Perhaps the same is true for SV models.

Comment: Yes, I just came to the same realization that probably with normal errors in the equation for the variance you indeed still can generate heavy tails for the observation equation. I also looked into $t$ errors but especially for SV models estimation seems very involved (it is already difficult enough for Gaussian errors). Thanks again :)!